# SMA, SVM and PSD python

Tags: python, frequency, magnitude

I'm looking for python functions (package) to calculate SMA (signal magnitude area), SVM (signal vector magnitude) and PSD (Power Spectral Density). The goal is to extract features from an accelerometer data.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`matplotlib.pyplot.psd`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.psd.html) to get PSD (Power Spectral Density): it returns the values for the power spectrum and the corresponding frequencies.

As for SMA (Signal Magnitude Area) and SVM (Signal Vector Magnitude), I am not aware of their support in existing packages. They seem to be easily implementable in one-line functions though.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will try it. although I am interested in returning values as csv files to be used for classification.

Comment: @Ziad Using csv files can be done with separate libs. Maybe you will find [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) helpful.